# Error when select multiple cells and press delete/backspace

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code. It does some stuff when specifically [G,g,Y,y,R,r] are pressed and there is an error handling in case other keys are pressed as well. This works fine!
However, when multiple cells in column 11 are selected and delete/backspace is pressed I get "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch".

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim TestCell
Dim RE As Object
Dim REMatches As Object
Dim Cell1_1 As String
Dim Today As String
Dim Cell As String

ThisRow = Target.Row

'Action happens when typing [G,g,Y,y,R,r]

If Target.Column = 11 Then

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

With RE
    .MultiLine = False
    .Global = False
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "[G,g,Y,y,R,r]"
End With

For Each TestCell In Target.Cells

Set REMatches = RE.Execute(TestCell.Value)

If REMatches.Count > 0 And Len(Target.Value) = 1 Then
    If Len(Cells(1, 1).Value) = 1 Then
        Today = Now()
        Cell1_1 = Sheets("Input").Cells(1, 1).Value
        Range("L" & ThisRow) = Cell1_1 + ": " + Format(Today, "ddmmmyy")
    End If

'Avoid typing another thing

ElseIf Target.Value <> vbNullString Then
     Row = Target.Row
     Cells(Row, 11).Value = vbNullString
     MsgBox "Please, type only:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "G for Green" & vbNewLine & "Y for Yellow" & vbNewLine & "R for Red"

End If

Next

End If

End Sub
```

The error occurs at this line in the code.

```
If REMatches.Count > 0 And Len(Target.Value) = 1 Then
```

Comment: What line is generating the run time error?

Comment: If REMatches.Count > 0 And Len(Target.Value) = 1 Then

Comment: I'm not sure what the error is at this time, i'm just looking for more info to help the community solve the issue.  What is the expected behavior when multiple cells in column 11 are selected and delete/backspace is pressed?

Comment: Just to clean the cell content. This happens indeed, but I get this error as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no lost functionality you can enclose that code in some error handling.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim TestCell
Dim RE As Object
Dim REMatches As Object
Dim Cell1_1 As String
Dim Today As String
Dim Cell As String

ThisRow = Target.Row

'Action happens when typing [G,g,Y,y,R,r]

If Target.Column = 11 Then

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

With RE
.MultiLine = False
.Global = False
.IgnoreCase = True
.Pattern = "[G,g,Y,y,R,r]"
End With

For Each TestCell In Target.Cells

Set REMatches = RE.Execute(TestCell.Value)

On Error Goto Skip    '************Error Handle*************
If REMatches.Count > 0 And Len(Target.Value) = 1 Then
    If Len(Cells(1, 1).Value) = 1 Then
        Today = Now()
        Cell1_1 = Sheets("Input").Cells(1, 1).Value
        Range("L" & ThisRow) = Cell1_1 + ": " + Format(Today, "ddmmmyy")
    End If

'Avoid typing another thing

ElseIf Target.Value <> vbNullString Then
     Row = Target.Row
     Cells(Row, 11).Value = vbNullString
     MsgBox "Please, type only:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "G for Green" &     vbNewLine & "Y for Yellow" & vbNewLine & "R for Red"

End If

Skip:            '************Error Handle*************
On Error goto 0  '************Error Handle*************

Next

End If

End Sub
```

Or if the code still needs to execute

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim TestCell
Dim RE As Object
Dim REMatches As Object
Dim Cell1_1 As String
Dim Today As String
Dim Cell As String

ThisRow = Target.Row

'Action happens when typing [G,g,Y,y,R,r]

If Target.Column = 11 Then

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

With RE
.MultiLine = False
.Global = False
.IgnoreCase = True
.Pattern = "[G,g,Y,y,R,r]"
End With

For Each TestCell In Target.Cells

Set REMatches = RE.Execute(TestCell.Value)

On Error Resume Next    '************Error Handle*************
If REMatches.Count > 0 And Len(Target.Value) = 1 Then
    If Len(Cells(1, 1).Value) = 1 Then
        Today = Now()
        Cell1_1 = Sheets("Input").Cells(1, 1).Value
        Range("L" & ThisRow) = Cell1_1 + ": " + Format(Today, "ddmmmyy")
    End If

'Avoid typing another thing

ElseIf Target.Value <> vbNullString Then
     Row = Target.Row
     Cells(Row, 11).Value = vbNullString
     MsgBox "Please, type only:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "G for Green" &     vbNewLine & "Y for Yellow" & vbNewLine & "R for Red"

End If

On Error goto 0  '************Error Handle*************

Next

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Matthew, I didn't know about that method. I've only placed it before "If Target.Column = 11 Then"and worked perfectly! Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: @Felipe A word of caution, you should be careful with "resume next". It can "hide" other error conditions from you.  So if you use that, i would only put it around code where you know that it is ok if something doesn't work.  And use the "on error goto 0" after that code so vba will start displaying errors again.